# problem in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I made a dictionary, then split up the values and keys into lists and now its looks like this:

```
keys = [(4,5),(5,6),(4,8)......so on].
values = [('west',1),('south',1).......]
```

Then I made a new dictionary like in this way,

```
final = dict((k,v[0]) for k,v in zip(keys, values))
```

When I execute -print final - output is in this form... `{(4,5):west,(5,6):south,......so on}`

Now i need to have the value of key (4,5)...it can be any key..

q:2

```
win = gap.pop() - here gap is a stack
         print win      - the output is (1,1)
         return final.get(win) -
```

but when I do this return, it gives me an error and final is the directory that I have made with lists of keys and values

The error is: 'W'

Comment: @Shilpa: You are the OP.

Comment: Shilpa, instead of editing and adding a new question, just start a new question.  Also, it's probably more helpful to copy/paste code and error messages.  Things get left out otherwise and it's hard to guess.  For example. the error message "W" -- there has to be be more than just that.

Comment: oh god...wat shud i do now...When I post a similar question,.,,everybody here start saying that u shud not post the similar question again...u can edit the previous one...but now you r saying something else...but anyways...I am sorry...I'll keep it in my mind....And the error is only "w" .....This W is coming bcoz the value of (1,1) is west..so only w is coming out...

Comment: @Shilpa: I see you ask a lot about python and every question gives you a new piece for your application. Seriously, this won't help you. **Learn Python before you use it.** SO is not for learning a language, it is for helping with specific problems. But it seems you gain the most if you first read a Python tutorial and follow some code examples.

Comment: I am sorry....I'll not repeat this mistake...I am posting the whole new question with lil code ...

Comment: I have to submit the project next week...And i have never worked on it...thats y..m getting so questions...

Comment: Then you better spend a day and read documentation and actually *learn* something. You will gain more from that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274889/error-in-executing-python-code-dictionary-problem  -----link to my othr question...I dont have any debugger....I wanted to use...eclipse with pydev....but...I prefer to ask doubts...It is also giving me new ways to handle queries...it is also a learning proceess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
>>> final = {(4,5):"West", (5,6): "East"}
>>> print final
{(4, 5): 'West', (5, 6): 'East'}
>>> final[(4,5)]
'West'
```

You might want to try `final.get((4,5))`.

Or post more code, maybe you do something fancy with `final`. If you don't get a value back, you should at least get a `KeyError`:

```
>>> final[(7,8)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: (7, 8)
```

In this case you either have to handle the exception:

```
try:
    final[(7,8)]
except KeyError:
    print "Key not in dict."
```

or use `final.get((7,8), <default value>)` which will return `<default value>` if the key is not found (or `None` if you don't specify a default value).

---

[**Read about dictionaries in the Python documentation**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Comment: `print final[(4,5)]` gives me `west` as well. There must be something missing from the OP's question.

Comment: Awesome....final.get((4,5)) works for me...thanks  
But i have 1 more question related to this thing...I am editing the question...plz see it and tell me the right way of doing it...once again..thanks

Comment: @Shilpa: You're welcome, but it seems you have not stated your problem correctly. First you said, `final[(4,5)]` does not give you `west` but we could show you that it does. Later in a comment you say that you get a key error for `(5,3)`, but you never mentioned this in your question. Please be *specific* about your problem, we don't want to *guess*.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I am not getting the result for any number. Only the final.get gives me the result. I dont see, weher I used (5,3)..bt leave it now, its not an issue....I need to find the soln of my next error.....why is that so ?/

Comment: @Shilpa: You should create a new question and post more complete code. Your code pieces are to small and we have to guess a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
>>> keys=[(4,5),(5,6)]
>>> values = ["west","south"]
>>> f=dict(zip(keys,values))
>>> f
{(4, 5): 'west', (5, 6): 'south'}
>>> f[(4,5)]
'west'
```

Comment: KeyError: (5, 3)

This is wat i am getting

Comment: @Shilpa: Well, then the key `(5,3)` is obviously not in your dictionary. From the code you posted so far it seems you have `(a,b)`, where `a < b`, but `5` is larger than `3`. If you print `final`, do you see a key `(5,3)`? I bet not ;)