# Error in executing python code- dictionary problem

Tags: python, dictionary

```
while stack.isEmpty() != 1:
             fin = stack.pop()
         print fin            - output is (1,1)
         k = final.get(fin)
         return k

def directionToVector(direction, speed = 1.0):
    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
    return (dx * speed, dy * speed)
  directionToVector = staticmethod(directionToVector)
```

but when I do this return, it gives me an error and final is the directory that I have made with lists of keys and values

The error is:

```
File "line 212, in directionToVector
    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
KeyError: 'W'
```

Comment: I think `while not stack.isEmpty():` looks a bit better

Comment: Or `while stack:` assuming it is a list.

Comment: ys...bt it doesnt make n]any differnce in the output

Comment: Can you post more of the code *before* `while stack.isEmpty() != 1:` ? And where do you call `directionToVector` ?

Comment: I'm not calling diretionToVector anywhere in my code...there is a file in which this func is already defined.There are lots of functions that are in other files that are running like...illegal direction, total cost...etc...

Comment: Seriously I think you will get better help if you ask a fellow student. We just don't know enough about your code, your overall problem and I think this is a bit too much to communicate via SO. It feels like you basically want us to do your project and that is not what SO is for. I'm sorry.

Comment: Again, like in your other questions, you are not printing the entire stack trace, making it very difficult for other SO users to help you!

I also think these questions should be tagged `homework`.

Answer (score 1):

`Actions._directions` is presumably a dictionary, so the line:

```
dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
```

at runtime (based on the error message) is:

```
dx, dy =  Actions._directions["W"]
```

and it's complaining that there's no key "W" in that dictionary.  So you should check to see that you've actually added that key with some value in there.  Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
dx, dy =  Actions._directions.get(direction, (0, 0))
```

where (0, 0) can be any default value you choose when there's no such key.  Another possibility is to handle the error explicitly:

```
try:
    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
except KeyError:
    # handle the error for missing key
```

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
KeyError: 'W'
```

means that the key you requested ('W') is not one of the keys that are stored in the dictionary. This is because your dictionary key is 'west' not 'W' (see your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274762/problem-in-dictionary-python)). Try this instead:

```
key = { 'N' : 'north', 'S' : 'south', 'E' : 'east', 'W' : 'west' }[direction]
dx, dy =  Actions._directions[key]
```

Alternatively, make sure you pass the string 'west' to `directionToVector` and not the string 'W'.

Comment: But I have to keep the key as(1,1), (4,5)..in this format so that I can go back to my path by referencing this key and get the direction related to this key. I cant change the finction "def directionvector"...I am not allowed to do that....

Comment: I think you're confusing keys with values.  The keys are "west", "north", etc, and the values are (1, 1), (4, 5), etc.

Comment: @Shilpa: Why are you not allowed to change the definition? Your teacher said this? Besides you don't need to change the definition, just how it is called.

Comment: my teacher told me to make changes in only 1 file....dont touch other files...Bcoz they asked me to submit my code only..and they will run it in their system with other files keeping unchanged...

Comment: my dict output is in this order: {(5, 4): 'North', (1, 3): 'West', (5, 5): 'North', (4, 5): 'East'............so on....so here the key is (5,4) and value is North...is it right??